# What is the fastest way to empty a range of elements from the DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery

My layout (simplified) is the following

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="row_section">
    <div class="row_section">
    ...
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="row_section">
    ...
</div>
...
```

and I want to figure out the fastest way to empty all the divs that have class="row" in a certain interval (say from 0 to 59)

So far I've tried a lot of options:

```
$j('div.row').slice(nr_i, nr_s).empty();
```

surprisingly takes longer than

```
for(i = nr_i; i < nr_s; i++) {
    $j('div.row:eq('+i+')').empty();
}
```

and in an example where there are .row_section divs only in the selected interval,

```
$j('div.row_section').remove();
```

is the fastest BUT it's still not fast enough. It takes twice as much to empty a section of 60 rows than it is to create a new one, almost 3 times as much actually.

Considering creating the rows involves more claculations than just adding a bunch of sections (the sections also have other stuff in them and there's a lot of sections per row) I would think creating them would take longer.

What's the fastest way of doing the original task, and why is it taking so much more to empty (with the fastest solution) than to create new ones?

I would also like to add that the row elements can go into the thousands yet there are never more than 60-80 non-empty rows, and row_sections go to the hundreds per row. Yes, I know it's impractical to do this in a web app but alas, it's what has to be done.

Comment: Which browsers did you measure this on? You can't just say "A takes longer than B" and not tell us the specific browser. Especially such a special case is hardly ever the same cross-browser. By the way, I would throw it all away and create the section new, something you mentioned too. Another thing: Operations on the live DOM are faster when the parent element is display:none, especially when operations are done in sequence instead of a single step.

Comment: I'm testing this on firefox, with firebug activated. Sorry for not mentioning it.

Comment: If you want speed, you have to stop using jQuery for the operation and make sure you don't have any `.data()` items for the deleted object and jQuery event handlers on the deleted items.  The issue with jQuery is that it has a lot of housekeeping to do to clean up all it's extra data structures whereas a plain `.removeChild()` can be quite quick.

Comment: there is nothing interactive inside the rows or the row_sections, it's basically only a very complicated grid-like... thing. It's basically only divs with 3-6 classes that determine size, color, borders, stuff like that.

Comment: Give removing it entirely a try, and recreate (via innerHTML in a single step). From your example it looks like you really remove almost everything under a certain container anyway.

Comment: @Mörre I have already selected an answer but I did try your suggestion. The result is a little slower than the selected answer. Seems like innerHTML = '' is faster than removing it and creating it again empty.

Comment: I meant deleting the container, just one element, not doing this in a loop for every sub-element. Just saying because I'm unsure if you think I wanted to have a variation on the selected answer, which I would not because that would be obviously slower to recreate them one by one.

Comment: I tried removing every .row and recreating it as it used to be, just empty. Is that not what you meant? I can't delete anything above the row in the dom because that would pose even greater problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("row");
for(i=0; i<elements.length; i++)
{
    elements[i].innerHTML = '';
}
```

Comment: This might just be the fastest way. Actually rocket fast compared to what I tried. I should stop using jQuery for everything it seems.

Comment: It is actually the fastest, down to 85ms from the 1000ms or more I used to get.

Comment: Using the DOM API where possible is the fastest way I've found.

Answer (score 1):

According to the jQuery code, the `slice` method perform a native `slice` then call the `jQuery.merge` method. And the `merge` method does a loop on each element in the current jQuery collection.

So in your second example, you make just one loop. In your first example, you make a slice, then a loop for the merge, then a second loop to apply the `empty` method to all element in your collection.

I think the fastest solution is to use the navigator `querySelectorAll` method (jQuery use this method when you use a standard CSS selector). Try to construct a big CSS selector like `div.row:eq(1), div.row:eq(2), div.row:eq(3) ...` and use it to do this : `$(selector).empty()`;

Comment: Makes sense; I assumed it would be smarter than that. I should've read the documentation on `slice` more thoroughly

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you try it:

```
function removeRow(fromV, toV){
  $('div.row').each(function(i){
    if(i >= fromV && <= toV){ 
      $(this).remove();
    }
  });
}
```

Another try:

```
function removeRow(fromV, toV){
      var i = fromV;
      while(i <= toV){
          $('div.row').eq(i).remove();
          i++;
      }
    }
```

Comment: Because then I would be going trough all the rows, which could be in the thousands or even tens of thousands to reach a section of 60 rows. It doesn't seem very efficient to me, tho I could try it really fast.

Comment: This is similar to something I have tried (see second example) and it's not quite as fast as John's answer. It seems the solution here is to not use jQuery at all.

Answer (score 0):

Another option, which doesn't incur extra query selector parses:

```
var divs = $j('div.row');
for(var i = nr_i; i < nr_s; i++) {
    divs.eq(i).empty();
}
```